# Error Calling NPObject

Tags: javascript, android

I am using jquery with my android application. I successfully run my project when i am testing it on 2.1,3.0 but when i test it with 4.1 then it shows me error like " Error Calling method on NPObject" so please suggest me if jquery or any js needs any when version changes. I am describing here the code where i actually getting the error, actually i am pasting the code from jquery.min.js.

i am getting error in 3rd line in this method :

```
function warn(message) {
            if (window.console !== undefined && jQTSettings.debug === true) {
                console.warn(message);
            }
        }
```

and this method is calling from :

```
// Unfortunately, we can not assume the "tap" event
    // is being used for links, forms, etc.
    function clickHandler(e) {
        // Figure out whether to prevent default
        var $el = $(e.target);

        // Find the nearest tappable ancestor
        if (!$el.is(touchSelectors.join(', '))) {
            $el = $(e.target).closest(touchSelectors.join(', '));
        }

        // Prevent default if we found an internal link (relative or absolute)
        if ($el && $el.prop('href') && !$el.isExternalLink()) {
            warn('Need to prevent default click behavior');
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            warn('No need to prevent default click behavior');
        }

        // Trigger a tap event if touchstart is not on the job
        if ($.support.touch) {
            warn('Not converting click to a tap event because touch handler is on the job');
        } else {
            warn('Converting click event to a tap event because touch handlers are not present or off');
            $(e.target).trigger('tap', e);
        }

    }
```

Please suggest me how to get rid off this error.

Comment: After going though so many links i got that it is the issue faced by programmers in the case of flash and some stuff is about to use internal interfaces actually i am newbie in js css so i have little knowledge for all this.  I face this error only when i click on a button or on a link in jqtouch.min.js on line no. 98 which has console.warn and it is running so many times in the process but only when i click a button it is showing error calling method on npobject.